# Why does my Akka data stream stops processing a huge file (~250,000 lines of strings) but works for small file?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

My stream works for smaller file of 1000 lines but stops when I test it on a large file ~12MB and ~250,000 lines? I tried applying backpressure with a buffer and throttling it and still same thing...

Here is my data streamer:

```
class UserDataStreaming(usersFile: File) {

  implicit val system = ActorSystemContainer.getInstance().getSystem
  implicit val materializer = ActorSystemContainer.getInstance().getMaterializer

  def startStreaming() = {

    val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
      implicit builder =>

      val usersSource = builder.add(Source.fromIterator(() => usersDataLines)).out

      val stringToUserFlowShape: FlowShape[String, User] = builder.add(csvToUser)
      val averageAgeFlowShape: FlowShape[User, (String, Int, Int)] = builder.add(averageUserAgeFlow)

      val averageAgeSink = builder.add(Sink.foreach(averageUserAgeSink)).in

      usersSource ~> stringToUserFlowShape ~> averageAgeFlowShape ~> averageAgeSink

      ClosedShape
    })

    graph.run()
  }

  val usersDataLines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(usersFile, "ISO-8859-1").getLines().drop(1)
  val csvToUser = Flow[String].map(_.split(";").map(_.trim)).map(csvLinesArrayToUser)

  def csvLinesArrayToUser(line: Array[String]) = User(line(0), line(1), line(2))

  def averageUserAgeSink[usersSource](source: usersSource) {
    source match {
      case (age: String, count: Int, totalAge: Int) => println(s"age = $age; Average reader age is: ${Try(totalAge/count).getOrElse(0)} count = $count and total age = $totalAge")
      case bad => println(s"Bad case: $bad")
    }
  }

  def averageUserAgeFlow = Flow[User].fold(("", 0, 0)) {
    (nums: (String, Int, Int), user: User) =>
      var counter: Option[Int] = None
      var totalAge: Option[Int] = None

      val ageInt = Try(user.age.substring(1, user.age.length-1).toInt)
      if (ageInt.isSuccess) {
        counter = Some(nums._2 + 1)
        totalAge = Some(nums._3 + ageInt.get)
      }
      else {
        counter = Some(nums._2 + 0)
        totalAge = Some(nums._3 + 0)
      }

      //println(counter.get)

      (user.age, counter.get, totalAge.get)
  }
}
```

Here is my Main:

```
object Main {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  implicit val system = ActorSystemContainer.getInstance().getSystem
  implicit val materializer = ActorSystemContainer.getInstance().getMaterializer

  val usersFile = new File("data/BX-Users.csv")

  println(usersFile.length())

  val userDataStreamer = new UserDataStreaming(usersFile)
  userDataStreamer.startStreaming()
}
```

Comment: It stops around the 165,000 mark of processed lines

Comment: I'd use FileIO (http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/#akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO$), you don't need the GraphDSL, and you should use the result of `startStreaming` so that you have a link to what happened.

Comment: Using GraphDSL is a requirement

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yes it is a project and I guess it is not a requirement, but I chose to use GraphDSL so that I can learn about it.  I see what you mean about using FileIO however with GraphDSL I can do Fan-Outs and Fan-Ins for branching which is really neat.  I wasn't sure if there was a way to do branching using FileIO streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s possible that there may be any error related to one row of your csv file. In that case, the stream materializes and stops. Try to define your flows like that:

```
FlowFlowShape[String, User].map {
  case (user) => try {
    csvToUser(user)
  } 
}.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy {
  case ex: Throwable =>
    log.error("Error parsing row event: {}", ex)
    Supervision.Resume
}
```

In this case the possible exception is captured and the stream ignores the error and continues.

If you use Supervision.Stop, the stream stops.

Comment: Thanks! You were correct, the csv file is corrupt at that line since it contains a newline character at a random position.  However, I tried your suggestion using withAttributes but it is not catching the exception.  I edited question above to show how I implemented your suggestion

Comment: Nevermind, I was calling withAttributes on the wrong flow... stupid... Thank you very much!